# is PayPal-PHP-SDK supporting to do payment to another paypal account?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-rest-sdk

I am just wondering that can i send payment to another paypal accounts using [PayPal-PHP-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK) or i have to go with [Adaptive payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/).

I have just gone through their document but didn't find this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [Payouts API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/payouts-overview/) ? You should be able to use Payouts using PayPal-PHP-SDK which is actively developed.

Also, there are [few samples](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/index.php#payouts) that could get your started really quickly. You [could setup the SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki) and [run samples](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/Samples) in your machine fairly quickly without any issue.

Comment: hoop hoop new updates from API, have to update composer :) :). Thanks Bhai :)

Comment: I am glad to see the excitement :) As a normal developer,  I would recommend to play around the Samples and change it to get your desired use case working, and then implement it. It would help you figure out any issues you may have before you spending a lot of time.

Comment: One quick question, by which id i can track payment or communicate with you guys if something goes wrong? getBatchHeader()->getPayoutBatchId()?

Comment: One would be PayoutBatchId, and if you get an error, you could get a debugId in response data, that you could help us find the root cause of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options: [MassPay](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/mass-pay/integration-guide/MassPayOverview/) or [Adaptive Payments API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/).

Adaptive Payments has more control over the payment and is the future direction of the Paypal APIs, so that's where I'd start if I were you. It supports SOAP, NVP, JSON and XML. MassPay has both a SOAP and NVP interface.